# Using Protobuf messages in a Pcollection in Apache Beam using Go causing an error

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, apache-beam

```
func processPubSubMsgFn(ctx context.Context, in *pubsub.PubsubMessage) v1.someProto {
    someProto := &v1.someProto{}
    if err := proto.Unmarshal((in.Data), someProto); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to parse address book:", err)
    }
    return *someProto
}
```

Causes:
bad return type
caused by:
encoding struct v1.someProto
type has unexported field: state

When trying to run the pipeline, In java I would set the coder for the message type, not sure how to do this in the Go Version of Apache Beam

Comment: I had to add beam.RegisterType(reflect.TypeOf(v1. someProto{})) to the init() function.

Answer (score 1):

From what i see in [apache beam sdk](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ac573882c9b1005c3802552cd6268254293b0002/sdks/go/pkg/beam/coder.go#L54) you should return `*v1.someProto` instead of `v1.someProto`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes you are correct that worked.